# Solving/Optimizing a linear system in a finite field (Z/2Z)

Tags: algorithms, optimization, linear-algebra

I'm trying to solve the following optimization problem.

A is a rectangular matrix with coefficients in the finite field Z/2Z (size less than 1000 X 1000). I have a system of the form A.X = Y (X and Y are vectors). And I'm looking for X such that the Hamming weight of Y is maximal.

In the best case, there would be a solution with Y_i = 1 for all i, and I would find it using the Gauss algorithm.  But I know it's not the case.

So far, I haven't found a better algorithm than a random/greedy local search, but I'm sure I can use some maths to get a better solution. I've considered running a Gauss algorithm starting with B = (1,...,1) and  somehow backtrack when a run into a contradiction (and switch the b_i that prevent me to get a solution). Could matrix factorization help somehow?

Comment: Your problem is likely NP-hard, probably also NP-hard to approximate. But perhaps there are subexponential algorithms that give reasonable results for your dimensions.

Comment: I don't need to solve it exactly, but I'm sure I can do better than my current solution.

Comment: You might want to look into the block Lancosz algorithm for finding solutions.

Comment: Block lancosz algorithm  - does that give poly time bounds even in case of sparse number of entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note that a *random* assignment has probability at least 1/(1+$\hspace{.03 in}$(size($\hspace{.03 in}$Y$\hspace{.03 in}$)))

of making at least 1/2 of Y's entries equal 1. ​ That can be derandomized

by sequentially setting each variable to [something that forces at least

as many of Y's entries to 1 as it forces to 0, with ties broken arbitrarily].)

By [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.121.3302&rep=rep1&type=pdf#page=28)'s proof of Theorem 5.6, for all real

numbers $\epsilon$, if ​ $0 < \epsilon$ ​ then the [promise problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promise_problem)

Input: ​ instance of your problem in which each row of A has exactly 4 ones

must output YES if: ​ ​ ​ there is an assignment which makes more than 1-$\hspace{.03 in}\epsilon$ of Y's entries equal 1

must output NO if: ​ ​ ​ ​ for every assignment, less than ​ (1/2)$\hspace{.03 in}$+$\hspace{.03 in}\epsilon$ ​ of Y's entries equal 1

is NP-hard.

When [parameterized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_complexity) by the number of zeros in Y, your problem is obviously in [W$[\hspace{-0.02 in}$](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:W#wp)P[$]$O](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:N#npo),

but I don't know anything else about your problem's parameterized complexity.

[This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.128.75) gives a possible try for your problem,

although it looks like it's just a student's "3rd Year Project Report".

Answer (score 2):

This is known as "the maximum-weight codeword problem": it is the problem of finding the maximum-weight codeword of a linear code.  It is closely related to the minimum-weight codeword problem. For instance, if you add a row containing all ones, then there's a correspondence between the maximum-weight codeword and the minimum-weight codeword.

The minimum-weight codeword problem (for a general linear code) is known to be NP-hard.  However, there are non-trivial algorithms for it: I believe there are algorithms with subexponential running time.  (The problem has been studied extensively in the cryptographic literature.)  You might look at those algorithms; perhaps they can be adapted to solve the maximum-weight codeword problem, too.